# How to use case when when creating function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, case, conditional-statements

I need to use condition in my age calculating function but how can I implement 'case when' to compare if the person's age is 'turning' or 'turned'?

Here is my function that doesn't count 'turning' ages;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agecalculator(i date) RETURNS integer AS $$
    BEGIN
            RETURN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM i);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And here is what I want to make it work to check if one's Bday is passed or not;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agecalculator(i date) RETURNS integer AS $$
    DECLARE age integer;
    BEGIN
            age = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM i) - 1;
            SET age = CASE
            WHEN now_month = i_month AND now_day <= i_day
            THEN age = age + 1
            WHEN now_month < i_month
            THEN age = age + 1
            END;
            RETURN age;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Why SQL is so hard and not expectable? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with the `age()` function? But in generate variables are assigned using `x := ..` in PL/pgSQL not with `set`. You also didn't declare the variables `now_month` `i_month` and `now_day`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agecalculator(i date) RETURNS integer AS $$
    DECLARE  age integer;
            now_month integer;
            now_day integer;
            i_month integer;
            i_day integer;
    BEGIN
            now_month := date_part('month',now());
            now_day := date_part('day',now());
            i_month := date_part('month',i);
            i_day := date_part('day',i);

            age = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM i) - 1;
            age := CASE WHEN now_month = i_month AND now_day <= i_day
                        THEN age + 1
                        WHEN now_month < i_month
                        THEN age + 1
                   END;
            RETURN age;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```